# Change state from outside the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm using react native with expo and trying to get the current location updates while the application is running (active or in the background). But i can't change the state of the component from outside.

I tried using a static function the pass the location from the Task manager method to the component but it didn't work.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    location: null,
    errorMessage: null,
  };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, {
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Balanced,
      enableHighAccuracy:true,
      timeInterval: 300,
      distanceInterval: 1
    });
  }

  static updateLocation = location => {
    this.setState({ location });
    console.log(this.location);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ...
    );
  }
}

TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, ({ data, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    // Error occurred - check `error.message` for more details.
    return;
  }
  if (data) {
    const { locations } = data;
    // do something with the locations captured in the background
    App.updateLocation(locations[0]);
  }
});
```

I want to change the state depending on location updates. The error that comes is `TaskManager: Task "background-location-task" failed:, [TypeError: _class.setState is not a function. (In '_class.setState({ location: location })', '_class.setState' is undefined)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you are trying to call a function of the class, not a rendered instance of it. React simply doesn't work this way.

State can be passed from a child component to a parent, but only by passing the state update function as a prop to the child.

State can be managed externally in a number of ways, typically done using either redux or a shared context, which is probably what you need.

Comment: Thanks, i have used Redux to solve the problem using store.dispatch() and store.getState() methods.